# Calculating energy in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am calculating energy consumption of 4 classrooms together.In Netlogo I am doing a classroom simulation where students sit randomly in a seat and the corresponding electrical appliance (e,g fan light) turn on. Thus when all the students are seated the total energy consumption is calculated. How can I calculate the total energy calculation? Using the below code I am not getting the correct value. The is the time the appliance is turning on(becoming green). How should I approach? Please help.

ask lights [ ifelse ( color = green ) [ set l-energy ( light-wattage * ( time - temp1 )) ] [ set l-energy 0 ] ]
  ask fans [ ifelse ( color = green ) [ set f-energy ( fan-wattage * (time - temp1 )) ] [ set f-energy 0 ] ]
  ask acs [ ifelse ( color = green ) [ set a-energy ( ac-wattage * ( time - temp1 )) ] [ set a-energy 0 ] ]

Comment: What value(s) do you get and why do you think that the result is not correct?

Comment: I want to calculate energy consumption of each appliance. Students have different entry-times, and the appliances (e.g. fan,light and AC) near (have link with student) the student turn on after the student enters. Thus different appliance will have different on times.